# Input placeholder that changes every few seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, placeholder

```
<input id="home_search" type="text" placeholder="Kyle">
```

I'm looking for a solution that allows the placeholder to change every 2 seconds to predetermined other placeholders. Such as "John" "Sally"

Comment: u want the placeholder's to change automatically in every 2 seconds?

Comment: and from where you will get the new placeholder value?

Comment: I believe theres a jQuery solution which will allow me to enter 5 or so placeholders and have them alternate them every 2 seconds?

Comment: well this is a great question that why i tried hard to answer it it should be upvoted not downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this code its working perfectly fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var placeHolder = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
    var n=0;
    var loopLength=placeHolder.length;

    setInterval(function(){
       if(n<loopLength){
          var newPlaceholder = placeHolder[n];
          n++;
          $('input').attr('placeholder',newPlaceholder);
       } else {
          $('input').attr('placeholder',placeHolder[0]);
          n=0;
       }
    },2000);
});
```

> With the above code you can add as much values you want to the array it will work infinite and will return back to first placeholder when loop finish

updated working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5pwuqkbp/2/

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! How can I get this to work on an infinite loop?

Comment: Hmm, it's not quite doing what I'm looking for. I'm looking for it to go back to the original one placeholder after five? and loop that way infinitly?

Comment: Almost! but it currently only goes 1,2,3,4,5,1 I want it to go 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5... forever. Any ideas? Thanks for this.

Comment: well that was my error...fixed it check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5pwuqkbp/2/

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        setInterval(function () {
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    $("#home_search").attr('placeholder', 'John');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $("#home_search").attr('placeholder', 'Sally');
                    break;
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 2) {
                i = 1;
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is sample code, your code is better than mine.